# PHP in Javascript if mobile device

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

i have question, that i can't  answer by myself. 
I want to do the PHP code if a visitor is using mobile device. But, the problem is, that it execute the PHP code even if I'm one the PC.

```
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      document.write("
        <?php 

            if(isset($_COOKIE['web'])){
                /* nothing */
            }
            else {
                header("Location: /choose.php");
            }
        ?>
      ");
  }
```

Idea is to use PHP for detecting device, but some people told me that it's not working properly.
Thank's for response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sniff the user agent server-side too:

```
if( preg_match("/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && !isset($_COOKIE['web'])) {
    die(header("Location: /choose.php"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Because your php code is executed on the server side anyway. And javascript on the client side.

Comment: Yes, i get it.. but, how to fix it ?